# Atualizar array de objetos no MongoDB com Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Boa noite pessoal.

Estou desenvolvendo um chatbot, simples, para fins de testes, mas me deparei com um problema. Eu tenho um usuário, ao iniciar uma conversa, é gerado um bot, e esse bot tem um array de mensagens e respostas. Quero que a cada vez que eu mande uma mensagem, ele interprete, responda e tanto a mensagem quanto a resposta, fiquem armazenados num mesmo objeto. No entanto, atualmente, sempre que eu quero fazer um put, ele sobrescreve a mensagem anterior, como se não fosse um array!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia o por quê?

Comment: Leia: [**Postar código como imagem**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/60376).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela sua última imagem, creio que isso poderia resolver:

```
module.exports = async (id, data) => {
  await Bot.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
    $set: {
      name: data.name,
    },
    $push: {
      messages: data.messages,
    },
  });
}
```

Em *arrayLists* use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) ao invés de `$set`.